# Python Multiprocessing Jits

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I was trying to execute a multi processed program like this

```
recQ = eventQ = Queue()

def _getRecords():
    files=os.listdir(LOGDIR)
    for file in files:
       fileHeader = open(os.path.join(LOGDIR,file))
       reader = logf.LogfileReader(fileHeader)
       data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
       for record in fileHeader.readlines():
           recQ.put(record)                  
    recQ.put('Done')

def _makeEvents():
    while(True):
        rec = recQ.get()
        if not rec == 'Done':
            e = event._getOject(rec)
            eventQ.put(e)
        else: break
    eventQ.put('Done')

def _updateSQL():
    while(True):
        data = eventQ.get()
        if not data == 'Done':
            event = eventQ.get()
            sql._updateEvent(event)
        else: break

def _trigger():
    processes = []
    processes.append(Process(target = _getRecords(), args = ()))
    processes.append(Process(target = _makeEvents(), args = ()))
    processes.append(Process(target = _updateSQL(), args = ()))
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _trigger()
```

Now the problem is when i am starting all the process from for loop, they are getting executed one after the other. I ve tried a similar example on some simpler data it is working very fine with it. Can any one tell me whats wrong with my code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please first *simplify your code and try to isolate the problem*. You have a higher chance of getting an answer: some people will not take the time to do this work for you, here. Furthermore, this would also be a service to the community, as a question looks too specific if the code is too long, which reduces the chance that someone identifies his problem with yours. So, both for you and for future readers, please try to isolate the problem and make the code shorter.

Comment: Ya but I cant find any thing to cut out from that code as they need to know what is happening inside the functions...

Comment: The `print` functions could at least be removed, some tests could probably be removed, they do not seem essential to the problem (`if file.startswith(…)`,…). If these obvious things are still there, it sends a signal that tells us that other things might also be irrelevant to the question and be in the code, which diminishes the effort people are willing to put in studying the question. That's one reason why people say here that the question should show some effort.

Comment: Hope that can get some answers now :(

Comment: `recQ = eventQ = Queue()` creates one queue and gives two names to it. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: there are several issues. You could start by thinking about the difference between `some_func` and `some_func()` in Python (`target` must be a callable).

Comment: Thanks Janne karila I ll rectify that...

Comment: Thanks Sebastian .. i ll get back to on that...:)

Comment: I think now i have cleared the multiprocess problem. But now, the event objects that i am keeping in the eventQ are loosing the values in them . when i was trying to access the values form the event object in _updateSQL it is returning a empty list. can any one tell me why ?